# Magepack Bundle Console Error On Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.4.4, jsbundling

After upgrading from 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4, the following error shows up in the console:

`Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function( $ ) {`

I've traced the error back to the generated `/static/version1657722773/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_GB/magepack/bundle-common.js` file, to this particular bit of code:

```
//>>description: Blinds the element.
//>>docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/blind-effect/
//>>demos: http://jqueryui.com/effect/

( function( factory ) {
    "use strict";

    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( [
            "jquery",
            "../version",
            "../effect"
        ], factory );
    } else {

        // Browser globals
        factory( jQuery );
    }
} )( function( $ ) {
"use strict";
```

However, I have no current idea how to resolve this yet. Has anyone came across this one before?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into similar issue on M2.4.4. Removing below files from **magepack.config.js** worked for me as temporary solution.

> lib/web/jquery/ui-modules/effects/effect-fade.js

> lib/web/jquery/ui-modules/effects/effect-blind.js

For more details please review this [issue](https://github.com/magesuite/magepack/issues/140). Hope this will help you. Thanks!

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Good to hear that it helped you. :)